# Unhandled task exceptions not being caught

Tags: c#, exception, asp.net-web-api, task-parallel-library, owin

The application I've been working on has recently started experiencing intermittent hard crashes which I'm unable to explain. To make this more weird we have both `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` and `TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException` set up to catch problems like these.

Usually when something goes wrong the above two work correctly, but we have certain circumstances where they are *not catching unhandled exceptions*. To make matters *even worse* the exception that's causing this is a NRE which means we have nothing to go on in terms of tracking down what's going on.

My first thought was that maybe the code we have in the unhandled exception handlers might be throwing exceptions, so we doubled down on exception handling here, but so far that hasn't made any difference. The logs we have also haven't been able to shine any light on this.

This may be a bug with webapi and/or the owin bits we are using to host the application, and I'm going to try bumping the dependencies to see if that helps, but I don't think it will make any difference.

Is there a way to trap unhandled exceptions occurring in the thread pool? Is there some kind of diagnostics we can enable to get more info as to where this is happening?

I'm at my wits end, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.Net.HttpListener.EndGetContext(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean     requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener.OwinHttpListener.<ProcessRequestsAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<ThrowAsync>b__5(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
```

When using tasks we do not do `async void`, but we have one case of `Task.Run` where we do not await or hang on the task. This is:

```
Task.Run(() => CleanUpAllExpiredErrors());
```

This method cleans up expired client errors (we capture client side stack traces on unhandled client errors).

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I'm not sure what's causing it, it could be any of our controllers or possibly signalr hubs... those are the only things that would use the HttpListener, but we have lots of these.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain we have no async void, everything either returns a Task or a Task<T>. There are a few places where we call `Task.Run` though.

Comment: Do you keep the task that the `Task.Run` returns and await the task or do you do it "fire and forget"? If fire and forget, show a useage example. (Also I am deleting my old comments to clear up space)

Comment: I'll update the question

Comment: @jonnii I have the exact same problem. Did you ever get to the bottom of this?

Comment: @Jon put an answer below, let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By adding extensive tracing and logging we saw that this crash was consistently happening when serving static assets, specifically stylesheets. We white-listed our static assets directories to not require authentication and the crash went away.

We configure certain endpoints to not require authentication by doing the following:

```
var listener = (HttpListener)app.Properties["System.Net.HttpListener"];

listener.AuthenticationSchemeSelectorDelegate = request =>
{
    // Options requests should always be anonymous otherwise preflight cors requests
    // will fail in Firefox.
    if (request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
    {
        return AuthenticationSchemes.Anonymous;
    }

    // here we add additional whitelisted paths
    var pathsWithoutAuthentication = KnownPaths.AnonymousWhiteList.Concat(KnownPaths.Assets);

    return pathsWithoutAuthentication.Any(a => request.RawUrl.ToLower().StartsWith(a))
        ? AuthenticationSchemes.Anonymous
        : AuthenticationSchemes.IntegratedWindowsAuthentication;
};
```

Comment: What host were you using - IIS, Self host? What sort of Authentication were you using - Windows, Cookie, JWT?

Comment: SelfHost + Windows Auth.

Comment: Ah me too, dont suppose you have a snippet I could look at?

Comment: Ran into this today.  Do you have any notion of _why_ it is happening?  Seems like a bug with the Owin HttpListener...

Comment: absolutely no idea why or how it happened, just found a way to fix it and moved on.

Comment: Fun...  We're doing exactly what you have posted as the answer and it still broke once.  Since it's one time out of millions of requests over the past two years, I'm tempted to chalk it up to gremlins.  Unfortunately it resulted in a hard, unrecoverable crash.

Comment: @EricRRichards yup this didnt fix it for us but we see it almost daily and have no idea of the cause at present :(

Comment: @Jon have you tried updating your nuget references? you might have something out of date.

Comment: Anyone ever get the to bottom of this? It's biting us at the moment, using v3.0.0 of all the Microsoft.OWIN.* stuff.

Comment: Came here while googling same problem. Setting httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" or above helped. Same issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39021872/async-await-task-null-reference-exception