# async await Task null reference exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, nullreferenceexception, mscorlib

I am getting NullReferenceExceptions on a webforms project I'm maintaining.  The catch is that there is no stacktrace for this exception because none of my code causes the exception.
[image: NullReferenceException was unhandled]

Exception details copied to the clipboard offers zero assistance:
`System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

When I view the non-user code stacktrace, I see the following (all in mscorlib):
[image: Stack Trace]

The error occurs randomly and inconsistently, either by loading pages or by postbacks.  The problem began after I added `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` for pulling data from REST services exposed on other sites.  Note that HttpClient contains only async methods for sending/receiving data.  Based on the internal stacktrace, I highly suspect the Task<> / async / await as the culprit.

To assist in troubleshooting, let me reaffirm that I'm running this in a WebForms site compiling in .NET 4.6 (and if you're about to tell me my problem is that I need to upgrade to MVC, save your keystrokes and don't say it).  While HttpClient exposes everything as Task<>, I am calling them synchronously by calling:
`Task<MyObject> myResultTask = restClient.GetResultAsync();
MyObject myResult = myResultTask.Result; // no await`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: just call await lol

Comment: @Steve no, [`Task.Result`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321468(v=vs.110).aspx) _does_ wait for the task to complete before it returns its value.

Comment: @RenéVogt if I remember right you can easily run into all kinds of weird problems without await

Comment: @Steve, @RenéVogt
I wish async/await was an option.  One of the uses of my client class is inside of an `<asp:ObjectDataSource />`, and according to [this submission](http://forums.asp.net/t/1065219.aspx?AsyncCallback+ObjectDatasource), ObjectDataSource provides zero support for asynchronous operations...

Comment: @JoeyHerrington: Do you have [`targetFramework` set to `4.5` or higher in your `web.config`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2012/11/19/all-about-httpruntime-targetframework/)?

Comment: Also, why are you using `HttpClient` in the first place? If you need synchronous web requests, use `WebClient`. `HttpClient` was specifically designed for `async`/`await`-style code, and `Result` and friends *can* deadlock.

Comment: @StephenCleary, huge fan, love your work, and your bio was beyond amazing.  I changed the `targetFramework` to `4.5`, but some other stuff in the site broke...  likely a symptom of stuff that needed to be fixed anyway.  This may take a while.  Meanwhile, I'll switch over to `WebClient` to get everything running again.

Comment: @JoeyHerrington: Long term, I'd definitely say go with `4.5` and upgrade the stuff it breaks. Short term you can try setting `aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext` instead (details [in the original blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2012/11/19/all-about-httpruntime-targetframework/)). That *might* work.

Answer (score 4):

I just had this issue and would like to suggest this as the answer.

In your web.config make sure you have the following:

```
  <system.Web>
      <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.Web>
```

and

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />     
</appSettings>
```

See more info here:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2012/11/19/all-about-httpruntime-targetframework/

It seems to just crash randomly if you don't do this. I am a big fan of backwards compatibility but not when it just crashes if you don't opt in to the new way.

(Suggested in comment from Stephen Cleary)