# HttpWebRequest randomly fails with async and await

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, asynchronous, .net-4.5

I would like to do serveral POST-Request.

My problem is that the Application crashes randomly in the `Task<...> do_POST()`-Function during `await` in my `async void bt_publishPath_Click()`-Event.

I can do some POST-Requests (everything's working fine) and sometime the `await` will block and the app crashes with a `System.NullReferenceException` (after a long time of waiting). I don't understand why this is happing because the first times it is working.

**Here is what I got so far**:

*I have commented out every unimportant functionality. I have tested my code without these lines of code and the error occures, too.*

```
// MainWindow
private async void bt_publishPath_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // gr_spinner.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

    ApiResponse res = await ApiCall.do_POST(
        "/path",
        getBasicAuthString(),
        flink.getJsonString()
    );

    // gr_spinner.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    // Globals.errorHandling(res.Statuscode, res.Parameters[0]);
}

// ApiCall static Class
public static Task<ApiResponse> do_POST(string apiPath, string auth, string json)
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        int statuscode = 0;
        HttpWebResponse response = null;
        try
        {
            // HEADER
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(apiBase + apiPath);
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", auth);

            // DATA
            byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(json);
            request.ContentLength = data.Length;
            Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            requestStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            requestStream.Close();

            // SEND AND GET RESPONSE
            /*
             * It seems to be that GetResponse() isn't called correctly.
             * The Backend doesn't receive a POST-request and the reponse stays null.
             */
            response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            statuscode = (int)response.StatusCode;
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            statuscode = (int)((HttpWebResponse)ex.Response).StatusCode;
        }
        return new ApiResponse(statuscode, null, new String[] { apiPath });
    });
}
```

**Additional information**:

Before doing this with async and await I tried to solve this issue by using a BackgroundWorker. In this case I had a similar problem: Sometimes the backgroundWorker of the previous POST was still busy and the program wasn't able to start a new one (deadlock).

Furthermore I have found something interesting: [async await Task null reference exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39021872/async-await-task-null-reference-exception)

- But in this case it is a ASP.NET-Application. I am developing a Windows-Desktop client - not a server application. So this doesn't really help.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Why `ApiResponse res = task.Result;` when you are `await` it?

Comment: 1) you shouldn't call `.Result` in an async method.

Comment: 2) you shouldn't use `async void`, except for the button_Click here. That you forgot to post. It is essential because it's the root of your call tree.

Comment: Is the button click method async? How do you call `postAsync`? Your code is a real needless mish-mash of synchronous and asynchronous.

Comment: @Rahul It's called after the await. I don't know another way to get the result.

Comment: @henk-holterman Maybe you can tell me how to get the result the right way.

Comment: @DavidG Here is the code of my Button. As you can see it's not async. I will give it a try. Thx so far.
private void bt_post_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ApiCall.postAsync(
        "/path",
        getBasicAuthString(),
        flink.getJsonString()
    );
}

Comment: You don't need to call `Result` cause that's a blocking operation. Rather just say `ApiResponse task = await do_POST(apiPath, auth, json);`

Comment: Don't put code in comments, _edit_ your question and improve it.

Comment: Ok, I have edited my orignal post, made my button async and moved the `ApiResponse task = await do_POST(apiPath, auth, json)` in it. Sadly I didn't help.

Comment: Don't change the question while you're getting answers. You can add a 2nd version.

Comment: And be more elaborate about "didn't help". Does it crash, hang, what's the error?

Comment: Good to know. Next time I will figure out how to add a 2nd version. I have got the same error. There is no change. `response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();` is null. And after a while I get `System.NullReferenceException`.

Comment: have you made any diagnostic on the server side ? any trace or log in IIS ?

Comment: @GCamel yes. There is nothing in the logs. Additionally I have just made a wireshark record and it shows that the client sends the request to the server correctly and the backend answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your catch block you have `(HttpWebResponse)ex.Response`.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexception.response(v=vs.110).aspx):

> If a response is available from the Internet resource, a WebResponse instance that contains the error response from an Internet resource; otherwise, null.

So your problem is a non-responsive server and an error in your error handling.
But don't fix this, look up the HttpClient and write a new `async Task<> DoPost(...)`.

Comment: Thx! `HttpClient` solved my problem. I have updated my questions and added the solution.

Comment: You can post your solution as a self-answer, that is preferred here.

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION**

Big thanks to Henk Holterman. He gave me advice to use `HttpClient` instead of `HttpWebRequest`. For everyone having the same problem like me: You will get HttpClient as a NuGet-Package.

**`ApiCall.cs`**:

```
private static HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> do_POST(string apiPath, string auth, string json)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response;
    StringContent request = new StringContent(json);
    request.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", auth);
    try
    {
        response = await httpClient.PostAsync(new Uri(apiBase + apiPath), request);
    }
    catch (HttpRequestException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        return null;
    }
    return response;
}
```

**`MainWindow.cs`**:

```
private async void bt_publishPath_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // [...]
    HttpResponseMessage res = await ApiCall.do_POST(
        "/path",
        "admin:123456",
        "{ \"hello\" : \"world\" }"
    );
    // [...]
}
```

Comment: You're getting closer. But also read [You're using HttpClient wrong and it is destabilizing your software](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/)

Comment: Thx for your link to this very interesting article! Actually I have already given thought to this - but then I saw everybody using the using-directive and decided to do it like all the others. But the article convinced me to change my code.